# Add tags to existing text

Tags: javascript, html

How to add new tags to text that is already present inside some element. Is there a better way than copying the text into new element and then deleting from old?

In the example below, text `Hello World!` is already present inside a `div`. The goal is to add `h1` around the text.

```html
<head>
  <script>
    let myFunction = function() {
      let d = document.getElementById("testId");
      let h = document.createElement("h1");
      h.textContent = d.textContent;
      d.textContent = "";
      d.appendChild(h);
    };
  </script>

  <style>
    .testClass {
      height: 100px;
      margin: auto;
      width: 200px;
      border-style: solid;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="testId" class="testClass">Hello World!</div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```

Comment: What is the text? Is it in a predefined region or is it the highlighted text? And what is the element? A p ? A td? And what tags do you want to add? Please add more specifics to your question

Answer (score 1):

This question is likely going to get multiple opinions.

Mine is that you are doing it just fine using the DOM API. However, if you understand the performance and security implications of `.innerHTML`, you could do this:

```html
<head>
  <script>
   let myFunction = function() {
    let d = document.getElementById("testId");
    d.innerHTML = "<h1>" + d.textContent + "</h1>";
   };
  </script>

  <style>
    .testClass {
      height: 100px;
      margin: auto;
      width: 200px;
      border-style: solid;
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="testId" class="testClass">Hello World!</div>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click Here</button>
</body>
```